# Elasticsearch index tokenizer keyword not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a indices with fields like:

```
"Id":{"type":"string","analyzer":"string_lowercase"} // guid for example
```

In elasticsearch.yml:

```
index:
    analysis:
        analyzer:
            string_lowercase:
                tokenizer: keyword
                filter: lowercase
```

But filtering like this

```
{
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "Id": "2c4294c2-ca84-4f69-b648-8a014ff6e55d"
    }
  }
}
```

is not working for a whole guid value, only parts ("2c4294c2","ca84",..)

Interestingly, on other machine it work properly with same configuration.

Comment: Any typo here ? elasticsearch.xml is not for defining settings & analyzers.

Comment: Anyway, your analyzer definition look OK. I created a simple bash script to describe your case, you can run it yourself and see if it help : https://gist.github.com/dqduc/1d501fbf01cf58a1cb06

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a custom analyzer through elasticsearch.yml. There is a REST API for adding a custom analyzer. For your requirement, below is the required command:

```
PUT <index name>
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "string_lowercase": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "keyword",
               "filter": "lowercase"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```